# Adding column headers to listview dynamically

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, columnheader

I have a list view that I want to add column headers to dynamically.

```
    For i = 1 To MaxMatches
        Tempstring = "Match " & i.ToString
        ScheduleListView1.Columns.Add(New ColumnHeader() Tempstring)
    Next
```

The hover tip seems to indicate I can do this (I would post a picture of it, but my reputation isn't there yet).

But it doesn't like the syntax.

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably should work better:

```
ScheduleListView1.Columns.Add(Tempstring)
```

Comment: From your answer I see it's vb.net, so I updated mine, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a work around by calling a sub function in the for-loop:

```
Sub AddaColumn(ByRef ColumnString As String)
    Dim NewCH As New ColumnHeader

    NewCH.Text = ColumnString
    ScheduleListView1.Columns.Add(NewCH)
End Sub
```

I suspect there might be a better solution and I hope those smart out there will post one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a universal column add function by setting a couple more properties

```
    public function Add_column(byval ListX as listview, byval ColString as string)
        Dim NewCH as new ColumnHeader

        NewCH.text = ColString
        listx.columns.add(NewCH)

    End Function
```

Comment: You can also auto set the width property by adding..

        NewCH.width = len(ColString) + 5